# Pickle not saving file on mac

Tags: python, pickle

i'm using python 3.9.1 and I'm in a bit of a pickle (see what I did there). I am using pickle to make a basic save file but it keeps coming with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnnyli/Documents/Game.py", line 19, in <module>
    roomandname = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'save.p'
```

I'm using a mac if that changes anything...
Here is my code:

```
import random
import time
import os
name = "Unnamed"
os.system("clear")
print("Welcome! Just so you know if you want to save, type save into the console.")
print("What is your username?")
x = input()
x = name
room = "1"
roomandname = room + name
x = input()
if x.lower == "save" or x.lower == "Save" or x.lower == "SAVE":
   pickle.dump( roomandname, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )



roomandname = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))

print(roomandname)
```

Please can someone help?

Comment: Have you made sure the file `save.p` exists?

Comment: You forgot the parentheses `()` after `.lower`.  Without those, you aren't _calling_ the function -- you're referring to _the function object itself_, which is certainly not equal to `"save"`.

Comment: Also,`x.lower()` will never be equal to `"Save"` or `"SAVE"`

Comment: And since `x.lower` is *not* any one of those three strings, the file was never created in the first place.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `x.lower`.

You should use `x.lower()` because lower is a method

You can change your if from:

```py
if x.lower == "save" or x.lower == "Save" or x.lower == "SAVE":
```

to

```py
if x.lower() == "save":
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I would accept it, but apparently, I have to do it in 4 minutes *_*